# iMacros saveas results in empty CSV file in firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, imacros

i have a very simple script in iMacros for Firefox

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:head<SP>super EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*
```

i can see a file being created but nothing is in it. I tried this in IE and it works fine. What am i missing here? I am using Firefox 27.0 and iMacros 8.6 in Win 7.

Thanks

Comment: try to downgrade to firefox 26 and check if it works

Comment: Thanks @Bestmacros. I downgraded to version 26.0 that but it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually text was there but there were empty lines before the actual text, so when i opened csv in excel nothing was showing up. I opened it in a text editor and it was there. I trimmed the string after extracting and got what I wanted.